# Display content of specific directory from command line argument

Tags: linux

I need a shell script to accept a directory-name and display its contents. If input is not given then HOME directory's contents should be listed. (This should make use of command line argument)

Please provide me some hints and solutions

Comment: Why you need script for this? `ls` command is enough. Do `man ls` for more details

Comment: @jkshah agreed, but he may want it as a template to do more complex job with other commands or he just wants to learn.

Comment: @AmirNoori I believe OP is just posting assignment questions and making us solve them. check it's new post!

Comment: First i tried many time to solve my shript then after i posted here.. ok

Comment: @ jkshah and Amir Noori I am not trying to cheat. If you dont want to give answer then ok. but why should tell this things ???

Comment: @RadhaChristian dude I'm sorry(I said I hope not) but anyway I delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -z "$1"  ]
 then
  ls ~
 else 
  ls $1
fi
```

Comment: No its not working if i use command line then display same directory as i have in home contents

Comment: @jkshah no you need to check if the user did not specify argument to `ls` the content of home directory `ls ~`

Comment: @RadhaChristian  you should specify the command line argument(the directory you want to show its content) otherwise it will show home content.

Answer (score 1):

With the condition of showing not the current directory but the home directory, this may be easiest to run in a script:

```
cd $1 && ls
```

Comment: You don't even need `cd`. `ls $1` should do the job

Comment: @jkshah: Nope, then `./script.sh` will list the current directory, not the home directory, as he asked.